# GraphQL Playground not working with TCP transport in NestJS federated microservices

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I am working on implementing federated microservices in NestJS using GraphQL. When I use the normal GraphQL federation setup, the GraphQL Playground works fine. However, when I switch to using the TCP transport layer for communication between microservices, the GraphQL Playground stops working.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

**// user.module.ts**

```
import { ApolloFederationDriver, ApolloFederationDriverConfig } from "@nestjs/apollo";
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { GraphQLModule } from "@nestjs/graphql";
import { UserService } from "./user.service";
import { UserResolver } from "./user.resolver";
import { AuthModule } from "src/auth/auth.module";


@Module({
    imports: [
        GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloFederationDriverConfig>({
            driver: ApolloFederationDriver,
            autoSchemaFile: {
                path: "schema.gql",
                federation: 2
            },
        }),
        AuthModule
    ],
    providers: [UserService, UserResolver],
    exports: [UserService]

})
export class UserModule {

}
```

**// main.ts**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';

async function bootstrap() {
  //   const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  //   await app.listen(3001);
  // }

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.TCP,
    options: {
      port: 3001,
    },
  });

  await app.startAllMicroservices();
  await app.listen(3001);
  console.log(`Application is running on: ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}

bootstrap();
```

What could be causing this issue? How can I make the GraphQL Playground work with the TCP transport in my federated microservices setup?